# How to do a for loop with conditions in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

```
(i =="S"|| i =="T"){ if(result==0){fin="J"}
}else if (result==1){fin="Z"
}else if (result==2){fin="I"
}else if (result==3){fin="H"
}else if (result==4){fin="G"
}else if (result==5){fin="F"
}else if(result==6){fin="E"
}else if (result==7){fin="D"
}else if (result==8){fin="C"
}else if (result==9){fin="B"
}else if (result==10){fin="A"
}else{
print("IC is invalid")
}else if (i=="G"|| i =="F"){
if(result==0){fin="X"
}else if(result==1){fin="W"
}else if (result==2){fin="U"
}else if (result==3){fin="T"
}else if (result==4){fin="R"
}else if (result==5){fin="Q"
}else if (result==6){fin="P"
}else if (result==7){fin="N"
}else if (result==8){fin="M"
}else if (result==9){fin="L"
}else if (result==10){fin="K"
}else prin("FIN IS INVALID")
}else print("All is invalid")
}
print(fin)
```

I want to get the specific alphabet for the specific number in my data frame

The error i got was:

In if (result == 0) { :
The condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: We can more easily help you if you provide a **minimal** and **reproducible** example, i.e. code that we can easily copy and run.

Comment: Typo: `}else prin("FIN IS INVALID")`!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
if (i %in% c("S", "T")) {
    if (result %in% 0:10) {
        fin <- c("J", "Z", "I", "H", "G", "F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A")[result + 1]
    } else {
        print("IC is invalid")
    }
} else if (i %in% c("G", "F")) {
    if (result %in% 0:10) {
        fin <- c("X", "W", "U", "T", "R", "Q", "P", "N", "M", "L", "K")[result + 1]
    } else {
        print("FIN IS INVALID")
    }
} else {
    print("All is invalid")
}
print(fin)
```